# Defining The Initial App in AngularJS - Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the more verbose syntax to define modules and the app. I have blank HTML page that pulls in angular.js and then this file (app.js), and I get the error

> Uncaught Error: Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string from testapp.

Do I have a typo, or misunderstand the parameters. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

file: app.js

```
    angular.module('testapp.common', []);
    angular.module('testapp.controllers', []);
    angular.module('testapp.services', []);

    angular.module('testapp', ['testapp.controllers', 'testapp.common', 'testapp.services'], function ($httpProvider) {

    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should some like this

```
    angular.module('testapp.common', []);
    angular.module('testapp.controllers', []);
    angular.module('testapp.services', []);

    angular.module('testapp', ['testapp.controllers', 'testapp.common', 'testapp.services'])
           .config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
            }]);
```